# How to place marker when click anywhere on the map view in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

My requirement is, I need to show the marker on the `MaoView`, when user clicks anywhere on the map and also need to get coordinates (latitude & longitude) of location where the marker is placed.

Here's what I tried:

```javascript
class Maps extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            region: {
                latitude: LATITUDE,
                longitude: LONGITUDE,
                latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
            },
            marker: {
                latlng: {
                    latitude: 17.6868,
                    longitude: 83.2185,
                    latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                    longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
                }
            }
        };
    }
    
    onMapPress(e) {
        alert("coordinates:" + JSON.stringify(e.nativeEvent.coordinate));

        this.setState({
            marker: [
                {
                    coordinate: e.nativeEvent.coordinate
                }
            ]
        });
    }

    handleMarkerPress(event) {
        const markerID = event.nativeEvent.identifier;
        alert(markerID);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MapView
                identifier={"1"}
                ref={component => (this.map = component)}
                provider={this.props.provider}
                style={styles.map}
                region={this.state.region}
                onPress={this.onMapPress.bind(this)}
                //onPress={(event) => this.onMapPress(event)}
                provider={PROVIDER_DEFAULT}
                mapType="standard"
                zoomEnabled={true}
                pitchEnabled={true}
                showsUserLocation={true}
                followsUserLocation={true}
                showsCompass={true}
                showsBuildings={true}
                showsTraffic={true}
                showsIndoors={true}
            >
                <MapView.Marker coordinate={this.state.marker.latlng} />
            </MapView>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First of all, take an empty array for map markers.

```javascript
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    region: {
      latitude: LATITUDE, 
      longitude: LONGITUDE,
      latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
      longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
    },
    markers: []        // Here it is
  }
}
```

Then push coordinates of clicked locations as a new marker in array. Finally, in your `<MapView>`, render all markers:

```javascript
<MapView style={styles.map} region={this.state.region}
onPress={(e) => this.setState({ markers: [...this.state.markers, { latlng: e.nativeEvent.coordinate }] })}>
{
    // loop through markers array & render all markers
    this.state.markers.map((marker, i) => (
        <MapView.Marker coordinate={marker.latlng} key={i} />
    ))
}
</MapView>
```

Whenever you click anywhere on map, the location's coordinates will be added in `markers` array and as `state` is updated, `render()` function will be called again and all markers will be placed on map including  the new marker.

---

**EDIT**
[@FortuneCookie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5742004/fortunecookie)'s comment:

> To show only one marker on the map and when user taps on elsewhere the
> other marker gets removed, just like dropping a pin.

It is much more simpler. First of all, change `markers` array to single `marker` in state.

```javascript
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    region: {
      latitude: LATITUDE, 
      longitude: LONGITUDE,
      latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
      longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
    },
    // markers: []        Change this
    marker: null          // to this
  }
}
```

And for `<MapView>`, just change its children & `onPress` event.

```javascript
<MapView style={styles.map} region={this.state.region}
onPress={(e) => this.setState({ marker: e.nativeEvent.coordinate })}>
{
      // if state contains marker variable with a valid value, render the marker
      this.state.marker &&
      <MapView.Marker coordinate={this.state.marker} />
}
</MapView>
```

You don't have to to put multiple markers in array and then loop through it. Rather, you just put your selected location's coordinates to `state` as a single marker and (if marker exists) then just render it on map. It will automatically set selected location to the state and remove any previously selected ones.

Comment: But this creates multiple markers on the map. Is it possible to show only one marker on the map and when user taps on elsewhere the other marker gets removed, just like drop a pin??

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope that'll help!

Comment: @TalhaSiddiqi thank the lord for your help, i've been trying to find a working solution for a similar problem and nothing helped but yours. Have a good day!

Comment: I know this is an old post, but what would this look like if you use function based and useEffect/Hooks?

Comment: onPress is not invoking if we press on any icon on map.

Answer (score 4):

## For functional component

```
const [marker, setMarker] = useState(null);
<MapView
  //   ref={data}
  provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
  style={styles.map}
  region={region}
  zoomEnabled={true}
  maxZoomLevel={zoom - 3}
  minZoomLevel={2}
  scrollEnabled={true}
  showsScale={true}
  zoomControlEnabled={true}
  zoomTapEnabled={true}
  // mapType={'satellite'}
  rotateEnabled={false}
  showsUserLocation={true}
  userLocationUpdateInterval={5000}
  showsMyLocationButton={true}
  loadingEnabled={true}
  showsCompass={true}
  onPress={(e) => setMarker(e.nativeEvent.coordinate)}
>
  {marker != null ? (
    <Marker draggable coordinate={marker} onPress={() => Alert.alert("test")} />
  ) : null}
</MapView>
```

Comment: Thank You!! I'm using Expo and its MapView component. This was the perfect fix I needed. I couldn't find a way to register a press on the map otherwise.